# how to use loop with some conditions in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops

I need to run a `curl` command several times, and check the result every time. I used a for loop to check the output from `curl`, and I want to exit the loop when the correct status is reached.

The very first time the `curl` command is run, it will show me this output :

```
{
  "name": "organizations/org_name/operations/long_running_operation_ID",
  "metadata": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.apigee.v1.OperationMetadata",
    "operationType": "INSERT",
    "targetResourceName": "organizations/org_name",
    "state": "IN_PROGRESS"
  }
}
```

It takes time to complete, that's why it says `IN_PROGRESS`. It took around 30 to 60 sec, and if we run the same `curl` command after 30 to 60 sec then it will show the output below :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 409,
    "message": "org graceful-path-310004 already associated with another project",
    "status": "ALREADY_EXISTS",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo",
        "requestId": "11430211642328568827"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the script I have so far :

```
test=$(curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" \
  -d '{
    "name":"'"$ORG_NAME"'",
    "displayName":"'"$ORG_DISPLAY_NAME"'",
    "description":"'"$ORGANIZATION_DESCRIPTION"'",
    "runtimeType":"'"$RUNTIMETYPE"'",
    "analyticsRegion":"'"$ANALYTICS_REGION"'"
  }' \
          "https://apigee.googleapis.com/v1/organizations?parent=projects/$PROJECT_ID" | jq '.error.status')
echo $test
while [ $test = "ALREADY EXISTS" ||  $test != "IN_PROGRESS"  ]
do
        echo $test
        echo "Organization is creating"
        test=$(curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" \
  -d '{
    "name":"'"$ORG_NAME"'",
    "displayName":"'"$ORG_DISPLAY_NAME"'",
    "description":"'"$ORGANIZATION_DESCRIPTION"'",
    "runtimeType":"'"$RUNTIMETYPE"'",
    "analyticsRegion":"'"$ANALYTICS_REGION"'"
  }' \
          "https://apigee.googleapis.com/v1/organizations?parent=projects/$PROJECT_ID" | jq '.error.status')
done
echo "exit from loop"
```

Comment: Please describe what problems you are experiencing with your current code. That being said, bash's string comparisons are case-sensitive. In your text you wrote `Already exists`, but in your code you wrote `ALREADY EXISTS`. Which is the correct one? Also, you didn't say anything about `IN_PROGRESS`. What do you want to do with it? Your current test `$test = "ALREADY EXISTS" ||  $test != "IN_PROGRESS"` is equivalent to just `[ $test != IN_PROGRESS ]`.

Comment: whenever first time someone hit curl command then in result shown like this {
  "name": "organizations/org_name/operations/long_running_operation_ID",
  "metadata": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.apigee.v1.OperationMetadata",
    "operationType": "INSERT",
    "targetResourceName": "organizations/org_name",
    "state": "IN_PROGRESS"
  }
} and if i again hit then its show {
  "error": {
   name",
    "status": "ALREADY_EXISTS",
 }
}
so it take some time to show ALREADY_EXISTS so whenever it exists loop will be terminate

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the duplicated code, use functions.

Also, best practice to use `jq` to *generate* json -- it will safely handle any embedded quotes in the data:

```sh
json() {
    jq  --arg name "$ORG_NAME" \
        --arg displayName "$ORG_DISPLAY_NAME" \
        --arg description "$ORGANIZATION_DESCRIPTION" \
        --arg runtimeType "$RUNTIMETYPE" \
        --arg analyticsRegion "$ANALYTICS_REGION" \
        --null-input --compact-output \
        '$ARGS.named'
}

errorStatus() {
    curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
         -X POST \
         -H "content-type:application/json" \
         -d "$(json)" \
          "${URL}?parent=projects/$PROJECT_ID" \
    | jq -r '.error.status'
}

while true; do
    status=$(errorStatus)
    [ "$status" = "ALREADY EXISTS" ] && break
done

echo "exit from loop"
```

The `while true; do some code; condition && break; done` bit is the bash version of a `do-while` loop

Comment: above code is not working in my case my problem statement is whenever first time someone hit curl command then in result shown like this { "name": "organizations/org_name/operations/long_running_operation_ID", "metadata": { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.apigee.v1.OperationMetadata", "operationType": "INSERT", "targetResourceName": "organizations/org_name", "state": "IN_PROGRESS" } } and if i again hit then its show { "error": { name", "status": "ALREADY_EXISTS", } } so it take some time to show ALREADY_EXISTS so whenever it exists loop will be terminate

Comment: Did you try this code? I think it will do what you want.

Comment: I did just notice a bug: need `jq -r '.error.status'` to remove the quotes from the jq output.

Comment: i try this code it is not working and i also remove quotes from jq still not working

Comment: You keep saying "won't work" -- what does happen, and how does that differ from the expected result. Add `set -x` to the script to enable tracing, and put `declare -p status` before the condition to inspect the value.